# How can I do an "if run from ipython" test in Python?

Tags: python, ipython

To ease debugging from Ipython, I include the following in the beginning of my scripts

```
from IPython.Debugger import Tracer
debug = Tracer()
```

However, if I launch my script from the command line with

```
$ python myscript.py
```

I get an error related to Ipython. Is there a way to do the following

```
if run_from_ipython():
    from IPython.Debugger import Tracer
    debug = Tracer()
```

This way I only import the Tracer() function when I need it.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is probably the kind of thing you are looking for:

```
def run_from_ipython():
    try:
        __IPYTHON__
        return True
    except NameError:
        return False
```

Comment: More detailed IPython configuration detection (whether pylab is loaded and in inline mode) is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341757/how-to-check-that-pylab-backend-of-matplotlib-runs-inline/17826459#17826459

Answer (score 13):

The Python way is to use exceptions. Like:

```
try:
    from IPython.Debugger import Tracer
    debug = Tracer()
except ImportError:
    pass # or set "debug" to something else or whatever
```

Comment: +1 is more common in Python to try things instead of testing things