# Is it possible to know if you are in ipython or not?

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

i.e. can you do something like:

```
if we_are_in_ipython:
    do_some_ipython_specific_stuff()

normal_python_stuff()
```

I guess what I'm trying to do is very loosely along the lines of `#if DEBUG` in C# (i.e. using ipython as a debugging tool and command line python to run the code without the debugging stuff in there).

Comment: Isn't IPython mainly intended for interactive use? Then you probably know that you are using it.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5376837/407651

Comment: Ok maybe a concrete example will help. If I'm using ipython, I put the line `from IPython.Debugger import Tracer; debug_here = Tracer()` at the top of my file and then `debug_here()` statements throughout the file. However the first line generates an error from the command line (`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'colors'`) and additionally I wouldn't want the `debug_here()` statements to be called anyway

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376837/how-can-i-do-an-if-run-from-ipython-test-in-python

Comment: @user647772 If you want to write a library that supports additional functionality when in IPython/Jupyter, you need a way to case that off.

Answer (score 4):

Check for the `__IPYTHON__` variable:

```
def is_ipython():
    try:
        __IPYTHON__ 
        return True
    except: 
        return False
```

Comment: What if I have `__IPYTHON__` as a variable

Comment: Python uses `__name__` with leading and trailing underscores for
special system functions with pre-defined behaviour. It would be a bad nomenclature from programmers part is what i feel.

Answer (score 1):

As explained on the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5376837/407651), you can use the try/except method, or

```
if '__IP' in globals():
    # stuff for ipython
    pass
```

Or check the `__IPYTHON__` in builtin:

```
import __builtin__
if hasattr(__builtin__, '__IPYTHON__'):
    # stuff for ipython
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
if 'get_ipython' in dir():
    """
       when ipython is fired lot of variables like _oh, etc are used.
       There are so many ways to find current python interpreter is ipython.
       get_ipython is easiest is most appealing for readers to understand.
    """
    do_some_thing_
else:
    don_sonething_else
```

Comment: I would be glad to know why someone -1 my ans.