# IPython: how to automagically load npz file and assign values to variables?

Tags: python, numpy, load, save, ipython

I'm new to Python and I'm eagerly migrating from MATLAB to IPython as my preferred language for data analysis at the lab.

In MATLAB, after a session of data crunching, I would do

```
>>> save('myresults.mat','x','y','z');
```

and save the results of the variables x, y and z in a file called 'myresults.mat'. Later on, I could simply say:

```
>>> load('myresults');
```

and MATLAB would load the .mat file AND assign the stored values of the variables to the current workspace.

I've recently learned that I can do similarly for IPython using numpy, namely:

```
import numpy as np
a = 2
b = np.sqrt(2)
np.savez('myresultsinpython',a,b)
```

and later do something like

```
npzfile = np.load('myresultsinpython')
```

However, what I get is an object from which I can access my variables by:

```
npzfile['arr_1']
```

etc., but I loose all info on the original names of the variables. I know I could save the file by doing

```
np.savez('myresultsinpython',a=a,b=b)
```

but this is not that useful, as I still have to do something like:

```
npzfile['a']
```

to access the variable's value.

How do I both load the file and have the variables created in my workspace and their values assigned according to the values stored in the file?

Something like `np.load('myresults')` and be able to do `a+b` and get `3.4142135623730949 (=2+sqrt(2))` in return.

Comment: Please see :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504951/is-it-possible-to-save-session-in-ipython-like-in-matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
locals().update(npzfile)
a   # and/or b
```

In the Ipython session, `locals()` is a large dictionary with variables the you've defined, the input history lines, and various outputs.  `update` adds the dictionary values of `npzfile` to that larger one.

By the way, you can also load and save MATLAB .mat files.  Use `scipy.io.loadmat` and `savemat`.  It handles `v4 (Level 1.0), v6 and v7 to 7.2` files.  But you have same issue - the result is a dictionary.

Octave has an expression form of the load command, that loads the data into a structure

S = load ("file", "options", "v1", "v2", ...)

In general `numpy` and `ipython` does not have the same sort of 'save a snapshot of the workspace' idea that MATLAB does.  I mostly write scripts to generate (and load) the necessary data, and run them either as stand alone python sessions or run them from with in ipython.  ipython does have a good history feature.  You might also find the ipython notebook tool useful.  I haven't used that.

---

Within a function, `locals()` is different from outside it.  It is 'local' to each function.  There is a `globals()` dictionary that might allow setting variables outside the function.  But this style of programming is not encouraged.

The SO question that `Anurag` cited points to a `save_ipython_variables` package.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/save_ipython_variables/0.0.3  It saves variables with `pickle`, and loads them by doing something like

```
exec '__builtins__[name] = pickle.load(...)
```

With use of `exec` and `__builtins__` it is pushing some safe programming boundaries. So use with caution.  But a small test does work in my environment.  The same technique might work with `npz` files.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that reallly answers my question. So, doing "locals().update(npzfile)" after "npzfile=np.load('myresults)" gives me the variables in the workspace. I've tried putting this two pieces together into a new function, which i can simply call by passing the filename as an argument and have the function dump the variables into the workspace. However, this does not seem to work. Am i missing something here? Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing again and again, getting tired of having to load dozens of arrays each time in the way:

```
data = np.load("file.npz")
var1 = data["my_var1"]
...
```

Since I let computations regularly run on the campus cluster and post-process the results (numpy arrays) on my laptop, I really appreciate the free Spyder IDE (which btw runs an IPython console interactively), which has a Matlab GUI-like variable explorer that lets you load a whole npz-archive (or selective variables if you so wish) or spydata archive with a mouse click. It greatly speeds up my workflow with numpy arrays.