# Unpacking data with h5py

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I want to write numpy arrays to a file and easily load them in again.

I would like to have a function `save()` that preferably works in the following way:

```
data = [a, b, c, d]
save('data.h5', data)
```

which then does the following

```
h5f = h5py.File('data.h5', 'w')
h5f.create_dataset('a', data=a)
h5f.create_dataset('b', data=b)
h5f.create_dataset('c', data=c)
h5f.create_dataset('d', data=d)
h5f.close()
```

Then subsequently I would like to easily load this data with for example

```
a, b, c, d = load('data.h5')
```

which does the following:

```
h5f = h5py.File('data.h5', 'r')
a = h5f['a'][:]
b = h5f['b'][:]
c = h5f['c'][:]
d = h5f['d'][:]
h5f.close()
```

I can think of the following for saving the data:

```
h5f = h5py.File('data.h5', 'w')
data_str = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for name in data_str:
    h5f.create_dataset(name, data=eval(name))
h5f.close()
```

I can't think of a similar way of using `data_str` to then load the data again.

Comment: Have you looked at `numpy.savez`? It's not hdf5, but it will accomplish your task rather easily.

Comment: Is this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357851/creating-or-assigning-variables-from-a-dictionary-in-python ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rereading the question (was this edited or not?), I see `load` is supposed to function as:

```
a, b, c, d = load('data.h5')
```

This eliminates the global variable names issue that I worried about earlier.  Just return the 4 arrays (as a tuple), and the calling expression takes care of assigning names.  Of course this way, the global variable names do not have to match the names in the file, nor the names used inside the function.

```
def load(filename):
    h5f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
    a = h5f['a'][:]
    b = h5f['b'][:]
    c = h5f['c'][:]
    d = h5f['d'][:]
    h5f.close()
    return a,b,c,d
```

Or using a `data_str` parameter:

```
def load(filename, data_str=['a','b','c','d']):
    h5f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
    arrays = []
    for name in data_str:
        var = h5f[name][:]
        arrays.append(var)
    h5f.close()
    return arrays
```

For loading all the variables in the file, see [Reading ALL variables in a .mat file with python h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852481/reading-all-variables-in-a-mat-file-with-python-h5py)

---

An earlier answer that assumed you wanted to take the variable names from the file key names.

This isn't a `h5py` issue.  It's about creating global (or local) variables using names from a dictionary (or other structure).  In other words, how creat a variable, using a string as name.

This issue has come up often in connection with `argparse`, an commandline parser.  It gives an object like `args=namespace(a=1, b='value')`.  It is easy to turn that into a dictionary (with `vars(args)`), `{'a':1, 'b':'value'}`.  But you have to do something tricky, and not Pythonic, to create `a` and `b` variables.

It's even worse if you create that dictionary inside a function, and then want to create global variables (i.e. outside the function).

The trick involves assigning to `locals()` or `globals()`.  But since it's un-pythonic I'm reluctant to be more specific.

In so many words I'm saying the same thing as the accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467517/901925

---

For loading variables from a file into an Ipython environment, see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28258184/901925 `ipython-loading-variables-to-workspace`

Comment: I was looking for a function that would load an arbitrary number of variables, but in your second part you explain that this won't be very Pythonic. Thanks for all the information!

Answer (score 0):

I would use deepdish (deepdish.io):

```
import deepdish as dd
dd.io.save(filename, {'dict1': dict1, 'obj2': obj2}, compression=('blosc', 9))
```