# How to avoid pickling errors when sharing objects between threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, pickle, locks

I have a program in which I need to store a global variable into a file. I am doing this using the `pickle` module.

I have another `thread`(Daemon=`False`, from `threading` module) which sometimes changes the value of the global variable. The value is also modified in global scope(the main program).

I am dumping the value of the variable into a `.pkl` file every 5 seconds (using another `thread` from `threading` module).

But I found the following error when `dump` method was executed:

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

Why is this happening? And what can I do to fix it?

Note: I have found some similar answers with `multiprocessing` module. But I need an answer for `threading` module.

Code:

```
def save_state():
    while True:
        global variable

        lastSession = open('lastSession.pkl', 'wb')

        # error occurs on this line
        pickle.dump(variable, lastSession)

        lastSession.close()          
        time.sleep(5)

state_thread = threading.Thread(target = save_state)
state_thread.setDaemon(False)
state_thread.start()

# variable is changed outside this function and also in another thread(not state_thread).
```

Comment: you cannot pickle a lock object because it is tied to the curent state of the operating system / semaphores currently held by the other threads.

Comment: If you want to pickle a types which directly or indirectly references locks, you'll need to implement your own [`__getstate__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) methods. It doesn't matter if the locks are released or not, they cannot be pickled.

Comment: But when the target function is terminated, shouldn't the locks be released since there is only one thread remaining? Also if you can provide a sample code, that would really help

Comment: To discuss your code, we'd really need to see it. Can you show us the lock in question? Is it an attribute of some object that you're pickling, or are you trying to pickle it directly?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you cannot pickle "volatile" entities (threads, connections, synchonization primitives etc.) because they don't make sense as persistent data.

Looks like what you're trying to do is be saving session variables for later continuation of said session. For that task, there's nothing you can do to save objects that, well, cannot be saved due to their nature.

The simplest solution is just to ignore them. Replacing them with some "stubs" that would yield an error anytime you do anything with them makes little sense, as a missing variable yields an error anyway (it won't if it was masking a global variable but that is a questionable practice in itself).

Alternatively, you can set up these objects anew when restoring a session. But such a logic is by necessity task-specific.

Finally, e.g. IPython [already has session saving/restoration logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504951/save-session-in-ipython-like-in-matlab), so you probably don't need to reinvent the wheel at all.

Comment: Can you be more specific with the session logic in ipython? Also Can I store these volatile variables in a database ?

Comment: 1st: done, 2nd: did you get the gist of serialization and the "don't make sense as persistent data" part?