# How do I drop back to the python shell after exiting a script?

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x

My python script has a couple of sys.exit() calls to terminate under certain conditions. To test it, I open up a python shell and run `exec(open('script.py').read())`. Whenever I hit a `sys.exit()` call, the script terminates, along with the python shell, which is irritating.

So I try to get creative and attempt to determine whether my script is run from the commandline or from the shell by examining the stack. Source : [Detect if python script is run from an ipython shell, or run from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883394/detect-if-python-script-is-run-from-an-ipython-shell-or-run-from-the-command-li)

```
def exit_now(exit_status):
    os.system('pause')

    if PythonShell:  # how do I return to the python shell ?
        ???
    else:  # exit if we are running from the commandline
        sys.exit(exit_status)

...

# check if this was run from inside a python shell
frames = len(inspect.stack())
if frames > 1:
    PythonShell = True
else:
    PythonShell = False

...

if condition1:
    exit_now(1)

if condition2:
    exit_now(2)

...

exit_now(0)
```

How do I drop back to the python shell after terminating a script ?

Comment: lounch cour script with `python -i yourscript.py` instead?

Comment: You could also use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

Comment: ``sys.exit(0)`` returns me to IPython just fine when it appears in a script run via ``%run script_name.py``. Can you try to make a script containing just the exit command and run it like that? Are you even talking about an IPython shell (because that's what the question you linked is about)?

Comment: @pmos i'm using the python shell that comes distributed with the windows installer, that link was just useful info on how to determine whether a script was executed from within a python shell.

Comment: @mata I could do that, but was curious whether this could be done. This might have a couple of edge use cases ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
try:
    exec(open('script.py').read())
except SystemExit:
    pass
```

Answer (score 7):

`python -i <script>`

'i' is for interactive.