# Can a program detect if it is launched via shell or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, subprocess

The `ls` command is giving me a different *stdout* if `shell` is set to `true`. Why is that ?

Is there an underlying concept that allow a program (`ls` in this case) to detect if it is launched via shell or not ?

I noticed that both `p1` and `p2`share the same *stdout* on Windows, but not on Linux.

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['ls', '-la']
# Using shell
p1 = subprocess.run(executable=cmd[0], args=cmd[1:], shell=True, text=True, capture_output=True)
# Without using shell
p2 = subprocess.run(executable=cmd[0], args=cmd[1:], shell=False, text=True, capture_output=True)

print(p1.stdout)
print(p2.stdout)
```

---

**Output on Linux**

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 20 18:25 .
drwx------ 10 root root 4096 Feb 20 18:51 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  269 Feb 20 18:57 test.py

test.py
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect if python script is run from an ipython shell, or run from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883394/detect-if-python-script-is-run-from-an-ipython-shell-or-run-from-the-command-li)

Comment: I don't think `shell=True` makes sense when `args` is a list. The shell processes the command line as a single string.

Comment: @Barmar I checked by sending args as a string, the behavior still depends on whether or not `ls` was ran as shell.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's happening, but try changing to `cmd=['echo', 'foo', 'bar']` and you'll see some interesting results. When you use `shell=True`, the `executable` is used as the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python documentation is fuzzy, but the behavior can't hide from `strace`.

Your Python code:

```
cmd = ['ls', '-la']
p1 = subprocess.run(executable=cmd[0], args=cmd[1:], shell=True, text=True, capture_output=True)
p2 = subprocess.run(executable=cmd[0], args=cmd[1:], shell=False, text=True, capture_output=True)
```

Turns into (`strace -f -e execve python3 foo.py`):

```
[pid 143557] execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "-c", "-la"], 0x7fffc1235340 /* 34 vars */) = 0
[pid 143558] execve("/bin/ls", ["-la"], 0x7fffc1235340 /* 34 vars */) = 0
```

Which is equivalent to running these shell commands, which you can confirm gives the same result even though both are being executed from a shell.

```
ls -c -la           # Generally equivalent to: ls -lca
( exec -a -la ls )  # Generally equivalent to: ls
```

From this we can deduce the behavior.

If `shell=True`, the `executable` is invoked. The argument list is the `executable`, followed by the shell standard `-c` flag, followed by `args`. This makes more sense in the case of `executable='bash', args=['ls -la']`.

If `shell=False`, the executable is invoked. The argument list is `args`. This mimics `execve`.

So essentially no, there is no detection going on here. It's simply two different invocations of `ls`, and neither is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell *by looking at the return value* of the `run()` call like you are.

The returned value (`p1`, which is a `CompletedProcess`) does not store an attribute for shell:

```
>>> p1.__dict__
{'args': 'ls', 'returncode': 0, 'stdout': None, 'stderr': None}
```

Comment: Excuse me if my question wasn't elaborate enough. I'm not looking for a way to determine if a Python subprocess was ran with a specific value for the `shell` attribute. I'm trying to understand why `p1` and `p2` have a different stdout.

Comment: The answer to that question is “because one is using the shell and one is not.” What else are you looking for?

Comment: Of course that's the cause.

But my question is how does one program such as `ls` can detect if it was ran via shell or not ? It's not like there was some special value saying "run as a shell program please" sent as an argument to it. 

What's the inner working of this ?

Comment: AFAIK `ls` doesn't care whether it was run via a shell. It changes some of its output formatting depending on whether `stdout` is a terminal or not, but that's it.