# Import Module from different environments

Tags: python, import, module

Create a module in Python named 'python_1.py' that make the follow:

1. When import the module from Python console ('import python_1'), return 'Imported'.
2. When import the module from iPython console ('import python_1'), return 'Imported from iPython'.
3. When import the module from Command Prompt ('python python_1.py'), return 'Running as script'.

This is what I've done, but i don't know how to know where have been imported:

```
def python_1(): 
      print 'Imported from iPython'
```

Comment: Command System = Command Prompt?

Comment: Yes... sorry about that!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the following function:

```
import sys
def import_check():
    try:
        __IPYTHON__
        return 'Imported from iPython'
    except NameError:
        pass
    a = sys.executable
    m = '\\'
    m = m[0]
    while True:
        b = len(a)
        c = a[(b - 1)]
        if c == m:
            break
        a = a[:(b - 1)]
    if sys.executable == a + 'pythonw.exe':
        return 'Imported'
    else:
        return 'Running as script'

print(import_check())
```

The first part checks if the `__IPYTHON__` variable exists: if so you are running from iPython. The second part checks if you are running from command prompt or from IDLE (Python Console) as when you run from IDLE `pythonw.exe` is used to run the code whereas if you run it from the command prompt it uses `python.exe`. What the code does is it simply reverts the Python path to see which `exe` is running.

Disclaimer: Some of this code was written by @Dylan in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24188348/7541446) question and another bit was written by @Tom Dunham in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5377051/7541446) question.