# How to execute code only when executed as a VSCode Jupyter code cell?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I often develop notebooks using [VSCode jupyter code cells](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py#_jupyter-code-cells) like the one below and execute them via `python script.py` in tmux. The problem is that currently I don't have a function for `executed_as_jupyter_code_cell` and some code is executed unnecessarily. Can I check this somehow?

A workaround is to simply set a custom env variable, but maybe there's a direct solution?

```py
#%% load

def load(x):
    ...

if executed_as_jupyter_code_cell():
    y=load(x)

#%% transform

def transform(y):
    ...

if executed_as_jupyter_code_cell():
    z=transform(y)

#%% pipe
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def pipe(x):
    y=load(x)
    z=transform(y)
    save(z)

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as exec:
    exec.map(pipe, some_long_iterable)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if code is executed in the IPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411967/how-can-i-check-if-code-is-executed-in-the-ipython-notebook)

Comment: @tevemadar: When executing it via python it says `NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined`. My understanding is it only exists when executing it via ipython, but not via python, correct?

Comment: Ah, but I could simply try something like `try: get_ipython except NameError`. Hmm... there's certainly a cleaner way here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5377051/2135504 this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Well, yes, that's also a clue: when you can't access IPython/Jupyter API-s, you're running outside.

Comment: I'm fine with closing this question as duplicate. I didn't immediately make the connection between VSCode code cells and ipython but it's rather obvious looking back.

Comment: Revoked my close vote, one of the duplicates you've found would fit better.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work, but not sure how reliable it is:

```py
import os

def executed_as_jupyter_code_cell():
    return "IPYKERNEL_CELL_NAME" in os.environ
```